# React Native Unable to resolve module 'png' as a folder:it did not contain a package,nor an index file

Tags: node.js, react-native, babeljs

I got this error when I run my project.

The source code is below, tab1_selected@3x.png is exist in the right position.

`{
    label: '首页',
    screen: 'busdak.NewIndexTabScreen',
    title: '巴士驿站',
    icon: require('../img/tab1_selected@3x.png'),
    selectedIcon: require('../img/tab1_selected@3x.png'),
    navigatorStyle: {
        navBarHidden: true,
    }
}`

My .babellrc is below

`{
  "presets": ["react-native", "es2015", "stage-2"]
}`

I think maybe babel cause this error.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a fix for this error? I came across the same thing after updating to RN 0.49.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My RN version is 0.46.1

I used

`<Image source={{uri: 'picture name'}} />`

instead

`<Image source={require('picture path'} />`

fixed this error.

It works for me.

Comment: First, I use babel. Then I import a javascript library babal can't convert. So the project can't run.

Answer (score 2):

I think its a directory problem, maybe you are linking the problem to search in other directory.

I don't know your project folders but maybe the problem is at `icon: require('../img/tab1_selected@3x.png'),` try different version of that.

If your image is at `project_root/src/img/tab1_selected@3x.png` then u do 
`require('../../img/tab1_selected@3x.png')`.

Im not sure but i hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error some time occurs due to special characters in path. Check `-` or `_` or space in your image path. If you rename your image it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the picture name is correct.

Comment: off course name of image or path would be proper ,but I meant the special character in path may be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Try Restarting your packager..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of **case mismatch** in the path name. 
I am using VS code editor and it didn't give error for the path, but when I tried building the application, it gave me this error.

Comment: You can make it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Add babel-plugin-module-resolver module to package.json.

In .babelrc file

```
{
 "presets": ["react-native"],
 "plugins": [
   ["module-resolver", {
     "root": ["./"],
     "alias": {
       "@assets": "./assets"
      }
   }]
 ]
```

}

If your icons are in assests folder.Simply pass require('assests/sampleImage.png')  as value for key icon.